# Dealing with large integers in R

Tags: r, data.table, double, bigint, int64

I have an integer `18495608239531729`, it is causing me some trouble with data.table package in a sense, that when i read data from csv file which stores numbers this big, it stores them as `integer64`

Now i would like to filter my data.table like `dt[big_integers == 18495608239531729]` which gives me a data type mismatch (comparing integer64 and double).

I figured that since `18495608239531729` is really big number, i should perhaps use the `bit64` package to handle the data types.

So i did:

```
library(bit64)
as.integer64(18495608239531729)

> integer64
> [1] 18495608239531728
```

I thought integer64 should be able to work with much larger values without any issues?

So i did:

```
as.integer64(18495608239531729) == 18495608239531729

> [1] TRUE
```

At which point i was happier, but then i figured, why not try:

```
as.integer64(18495608239531728)

> integer64
> [1] 18495608239531728
```

Which lead me to trying also:

```
as.integer64(18495608239531728) == as.integer64(18495608239531729)

> [1] TRUE
```

What is the right way to handle big numbers in R without the loss of precision? Technically, in my case, the i do not do any mathematical operations with the said column, so i could treat it as character vectors (although i was worried that would take up more memory, and joins in r data.table would be slower?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing a floating point number to `as.integer64`. The loss of precision is already in your input to `as.integer64`:

```
is.double(18495608239531729)
#[1] TRUE

sprintf("%20.5f", 18495608239531729)
#[1] "18495608239531728.00000"
```

Pass a character string to avoid that:

```
library(bit64)
as.integer64("18495608239531729")
#integer64
#[1] 18495608239531729
```

Comment: Right! I should have tried `18495608239531729 == 18495608239531728` as well, which would tell me that the issue is already at the step before, because this already returns `TRUE`. Thank you for the clear answer!